# Launch external processes in front of full screen UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, console-application

I have a Visual Studio project with two start-up applications: a UWP and a console app. In the UWP I launch the Main Page in full-screen mode with

```
 ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

In the App.xaml.cs file. I then launch external applications in Program.cs by creating new processes and setting their filename to the .exe I want to launch. However, when I do this the UWP Main Page goes into full screen but I can't see the external applications. How to I make the external apps launch in front of the main page so that I can see them right away when I run the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to I make the external apps launch in front of the main page so that I can see them right away when I run the project?

For this scenario, you could minimize UWP programmatically after external apps launched, the app will switch to front automatically.

```
IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> infos = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoForAppAsync();
IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceInfos = infos[0].GetResourceGroups();
await resourceInfos[0].StartSuspendAsync();
```

Please note you need make sure the app's mini version is Windows 10 update 1803 (build 17134).